# Finding The Index of Element in an Array - Haskell

Tags: haskell

Which function can I use to find its index of an element in an Array?
For example, I want to find the index of `'x'` in an `Array` (`Data.Array`)

```
lowerCase = listArray ((0,0),(1,12)) ['a'..]
```

Comment: What if there are many `x` in the array ? Basically, arrays are for accessing by index and if you need to find element's index then array is not the right data structure.

Comment: Thanks Ankur. In my case, I know there is no duplicate data in the array...I wanted to access data by a tuple and that's why I used Array.  In that case, what data structure would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

```
fst <$> find ((== 'a') . snd) $ assocs lowerCase
```

Comment: Why doesn't `array` have its own `find` or in this case `elemIndex`  / `elemIndices`?

Comment: @Michael You can use `find` because `Array` has a `Foldable` instance. I don't know why there is not a `elemIndex` for `Array`.

Comment: Thank you! Just a small thing.. I added fromJust
fst $ fromJust $ find ((== 'a') . snd) $ assocs lowerCase

Comment: Eii000 what about when the element doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I check the output from "find ((== 'a') . snd) $ assocs lowerCase " and run the rest when it's not Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the indices a certain element appears in your `Data.Array` the following list comprehension can be used:

```
results = [fst x | x <- (assocs lowerCase), snd x == 'a']
```

`assocs` has the following prototype:

```
assocs :: Ix i => Array i e -> [(i, e)]
```

It basically flattens a `Data.Array` in a `List` containing `(i, e)` pairs.
For:

```
a = listArray ((0,0),(2,2)) ['a'..]
```

`assocs a` will output

```
[((0,0),'a'),((0,1),'b'),((0,2),'c'),((1,0),'d'),((1,1),'e'),((1,2),'f'),((2,0),'g'),((2,1),'h'),((2,2),'i')]
```

Now, in our list comprehension, we have `x <- (assocs a)`, so `x` is generated by the list `assocs a`.

The list outputed by the list comprehension will contain only `fst x` where

```
snd x == theElementWeAreLookingFor
```

Every `x` generated by `assocs a` is  checked and if the condition `snd x == 'a'` is met then `fst a` (the index) will be inserted in the output list.

Once the list is generated, it can be checked whether there are none, one or more outputs.

```
getElementIndex :: Array (Int, Int) Char -> Char -> Maybe (Int, Int)
getElementIndex a e
   | null results = Nothing
   | othwerwise   = Just $ head results
   where results = [fst x | x <- (assocs a), snd x == e]
```

A imperative pseduocode could look like:

```
results = []

for_each x in a.toList():
   if x.second == 'a':
      results.append(x.first)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Done. Hope this helps